# scope from class root, to inside init, to then inside touchesBegan?

Tags: swift, scope, sprite-kit, initialization

Inside this, I'm not seeing goesTo getting assigned to nextScene. I assume this is a scope problem, but don't know enough to resolve it:

```
//

import SpriteKit

class MenuButton: SKLabelNode {

    var goesTo: SKScene?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("test... did this get called? WTF? HOW/WHY/WHERE?")
    }

    convenience init(text: String, color: SKColor, destination: SKScene){
        self.init()
        self.text = text
        self.fontColor = color
        goesTo = destination
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        print("gooing tooooo....", text, goesTo!) // WORKS!!!
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let nextScene = goesTo {
        self.scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 0.25))
        print("going to", nextScene) // This is NIL! SO NEVER GETS CALLED!
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the actual scene transition working?

Comment: it goes to a mid-gray non-state. The transition happens, but to nothingness.

Comment: Can you add the print statement above self.scene?.view?.presentScene... and tell me what it prints

Comment: It doesn't get called, the `if let...` never goes through because somehow `goesTo` is nil, despite being something, and initialised, during init

Comment: Add the code in your SKScene where you add this label.

Comment: Yeah... I know... this is the way it's supposed to be done. I was hoping to bully the labels into being like ECS objects, wherein I can make them do as I please. Not the case. Next on list of things to learn is GameplayKit. But not for a while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127754/discussion-between-crashoverride777-and-confused).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is correct, you can simply test it making for example a:

**GameScene.swift**

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print("- \(type(of:self))")
        let helloScene = HelloScene.init()
        helloScene.name = "helloScene"
        let button1 = MenuButton.init(text: "HELLO", color: .red, destination: helloScene)
        addChild(button1)
        button1.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.midX,y:self.frame.midY)
    }
}
```

and you will see a red label in the middle of the screen with "HELLO".

As you can see also your prints looks good for both of your methods.

**HelloScene.swift**

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit
class HelloScene: SKScene {
     override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        print("- \(type(of:self))")
        self.backgroundColor = .blue
     }
}
```

**Debug console**:

[image]